# How notifier are delivered to the front end and displayed?

Tags: orchardcms

I have added message in Orchard.Notifier,I want to display this message to front page by custom,What should I do?

```
_notifier.Add(NotifyType.Error, T("An Exception has occured,error message:{0}", filterContext.Exception.Message));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service that's responsible for adding notifications to the current page is [`NotifyFilter`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/5b5eda6ae36dc2d7906599882165ef1e985cdc8c/src/Orchard/UI/Notify/NotifyFilter.cs#L106):

```
var messagesZone = _workContextAccessor.GetContext(filterContext).Layout.Zones["Messages"];
```

This adds the messages to a top-level layout zone called "Messages". As a consequence, all you have to do is add a zone called "Messages" to your theme's layout. You can see how the `TheAdmin` theme's `Layout` view is doing it [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/89c562c50216498ecf3b0a87d7ca8832005b4cdf/src/Orchard.Web/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/Layout.cshtml#L54):

```
@if (Model.Messages != null) {
<div id="messages">
    @Zone(Model.Messages)
</div>
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If that answered your question to your satisfaction, please mark it as the answer.